# Какой знак нужен в предложении?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, тире, бсп, знак

Подскажите, пожалуйста, какой знак нужен в предложении по модели: "Что бы он ни делал (запятая и/или тире) двигатель не запускался"?

Благодарю!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Чаще всего в такого рода предложениях можно увидеть **запятую**.
А чтобы лучше подчеркнуть взаимообусловленность частей, используют **тире**. Применять сразу два знака здесь нет необходимости. Я бы выбрал тире:

*Что бы он н**и** делал ― двигатель не запускался.* (Нужна частица НИ.)

**Примеры** из Нацкорпуса русского языка:

*Что бы он ни говорил, поддерживали сразу же шесть голосов.

Что бы он ни попытался им объяснить, они его не поймут.

Что бы он ни делал, как бы он ни ответил ученику, он все равно неправ.

...что бы он ни говорил, он с ее точки зрения судил себя* (Л. Н. Толстой. Война и мир).
*За что бы он ни принимался, мысли о сыне мешали ему работать.

Но что бы он ни написал, все было бы справедливо...

О чем бы он ни заговорил, чего бы он ни коснулся, все так и искрилось.

Что бы он ни написал, ни отчебучил, мы все равно будем внимать благоговейно.*

*Что бы он ни говорил ― я сделаю это* (Л. Н. Толстой. Война и мир).
*Но что бы он ни говорил людям ― все это для него самого не годится.

И ведь что бы он ни говорил ― видно же, что ему нравится играть в этакого мафиози.

Но что бы он ни протаскивал ― таблица уже все сказала.*

См.: [Тире в бессоюзном сложном предложении](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=151),
[Правописание частицы ***ни***](http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php?sid=82) (справочник Розенталя).

Comment: Великолепно! Благодарю Вас!